# Update Inner Join Operation must be updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Trying to update Purchase Order information in the case of Purchase Order revisions.

```
UPDATE tblPO 
       INNER JOIN qryPOLN_UPDATE_INFO 
           ON tblPO.POLN = qryPOLN_UPDATE_INFO.POLN 
   SET tblPO.[LINE QUANTITY] = [qryPOLN_UPDATE_INFO].[LINE QUANTITY]
 WHERE (((qryPOLN_UPDATE_INFO.POLN)=[tblPO].[POLN]));
```

Getting the "Operation must be an updateable query" error. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Have you got unique indexes?

Comment: Did you try `Update, Set, From, Inner Join, Where` in that order?

Comment: POLN is unique. The update data is temporary import data using the same unique key.

Comment: Not sure how to re-write this using a FROM clause. I'll take a look around.

Comment: Does the query use tables and or views? Also, the SET portion of the statement follows the Update.

Comment: The data comes from tables and is manipulated through multiple queries. Are you sure the SET is immediately after when using an INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I was using a Group By in one of my previous queries. If you put the data into a temp table and run the update off the temp table, gets around the error. Answer was found at https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Comment: Glad you got it. So did your original query stay the same?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks for your thoughts! I did see some examples for similar queries using FROM statements but didn't test any.

Comment: I was just trying to think outside the box as a first-response. That's great you figured it out.